# WCF OperationContract Tuning Instancing and Concurrency with TSQL

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf

- WPF .NET 4.0 application
- Currently hosted in Citrix
- MSSQL 2008 R2 back end
- DB size up to 100 GB
- TSQL search will return 100 objects at a time and hits 12 tables
- Most searches < 1 second and almost never > 10 seconds
- TSQL (SP) updates are one at a time
- Reads:Write > 10000:1
- A single database may have 100 active users but never more than 10
  active connections.
- The SQL box only goes over 25% when performing a data load and then
  stays under 50%

Moving to client server via WCF.  My first WCF.

- Since no web client thinking of hosting as a service in house ??
- Later will create a sister product and host on Azure
- Thinking to require sessions  ??
- If I am thinking wrong please let me know

Where I am lost is is OperationContract Instancing and Concurrency.

For search Instancing should I go PerSession?  And if so should I hold the SQL connection open?

Update is way different from search.  There are 6 different update OperationContracts (for different data types).  Update is one at a time and via the PK and will hit the source table and a log table.  That may make more sense as a Single Instance and ConcurrencyMode Mutiple and hold the connection?  If so I do I manage concurrency?

There is also a bulk update but I am willing to just treat it as a series of single updates for now.

Primary objective is data integrity, then availability, and then scalability.

I understand there may not be hard answers.  Any pointers or reference material?  How should I stress test?  How to mangage and monitor the process?

Have a lot of data to test against and I will report results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a blog that address my questions directly

[wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/15/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-1.aspx)

[wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx)

[wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/26/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-3.aspx)

PerCall
You may consider this instancing mode in these circumstances.

- If your service is stateless
- If your service has light-weight initialization code (or none at all).
- If your service is single threaded.

My methods fit all those criteria.  Once the channel is created the overhead of InstanceContextMode PerCall is no more than creating an instance of a class.  The overhead of connecting to SQL is also small as it will hold a connection pool.  I was making it too complex.

If someone has more to add then I would be happy to accept your answer.