# How to handle concurrency in WCF service working with a database

Tags: c#, .net, database, wcf, concurrency

Hello :) I am quite new to WCF and this is my first time dealing with concurrency of any kind, so please bear with me.

What I want to do is to have a single instance of a service, which will be consumed by multiple clients (no more than 10 or 11). I want the clients to wait for each other when they consume the service operations. This way I should avoid incorrect updates of an entry in the data base. The operations are fast enough so that performance should not be affected too much. Now Im not sure, but to my understanding, to achieve that I should use a singleton service with ConcurrencyMode.Single, is that right ? Any comprehensive read on how to  achieve that goal is welcome.

Also Im aware that there may be better and more elegant ways of handling concurrency, but Im very very short on time, and this method seems the simplest and fastest one to implement, if I have understood it correctly that is.

Comment: My question was different but I found some informative links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746424/wcf-operationcontract-tuning-instancing-and-concurrency-with-tsql I think I agree with Dennis but I am still learning.

Comment: Thanks, I will read those links. But Im still pretty set on Singleton + Single concurrency. My ration Reads:Writes will be 1:1, so several clients may try to process the same entry ant the same time, with optimistic approach, the first client will have the correct value to work with, but the other will have already incorrect values.

Comment: If you were set on Singleton then why ask. Databases are built to deal with concurrency.  If you need an exclusive lock then use an exclusive lock.

Comment: I was wondering if the Singleton plus ConcurrencyMode.Single combination works as described. Sorry if my question was not asked clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The worst you can do here is a singleton service.

Database engines (well, most of them) are well-suited for concurrent calls. What do you want to restrict their concurrent features for?

The best way for you is a per-call, stateless WCF service.
For data consistency, use [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). To simplify this you can use any ORM, like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx).

Comment: Optimistic concurrency is not a good choice in my case, I think. It is possible that a client may try to access an entry while another client is in the process of calculating values to update the very same entry. Then the first client will be working with an already wrong value.